# Appending a value from other Column when a duplicate is encountered

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I have this scenario where I have a group of duplicate records,for every other duplicate record in the set I want to make it unique by appending the value from the other column of the table.

Please see below the expected output:

```
Column1     Column2   NewUniqueColumn
ABC          A      ABC
BCD          B      BCD
EFG          D      EFG
DEE          E      DEE
ABC          Z      ABC-Z
EFG          X      EFG-X
```

I know one possible solution is to use the case statement with the group by clause as below

```
select
case when column 1 in 
 (select column1 from sampletable group by column1 having count(*) > 1)
then column1 +'-'+column2
else column1 end as NewUniqueColumn
from sampletable
```

However I was hoping that there can be better solution to this problem by writing lesser code,something like

```
select column1+ column2 over (partition by column1 order by column1 ) from sampletable
```

but I am not able to figure out which function i should use for column1 + column2

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually recommend *not* doing any DML on your current table.  It already has all the information you need to distinguish each "duplicate."  Just use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    column1,
    column2,
    column1 + '-' + CONVERT(varchar(10),
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column2)) AS NewUniqueColumn
FROM sampletable;
```

I suggest this because your current paradigm again breaks down in the case where a given `column1` value has *two* or more records with the same `column2` value.

**Edit:**

If you really want a verbatim query for your exact expected output, then try this:

```
SELECT
    column1,
    column2,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column2) = 1
         THEN column1
         ELSE column1 + '-' + column2 END AS NewUniqueColumn
FROM sampletable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Adding  a row number wont make sense to the unique key as it would be a random integer value,thats why i want to append column 2 value whenever a duplicate is encountered.

Comment: There is nothing random whatsoever about the row number value which is being appended.  And your suggestion to append `column2` breaks down when a given `column1` value has two or more records with the same `column2` value.

Comment: @Zee786 I have also included a query for your exact expected output.  But, I still prefer my first version.

Comment: i think the second version will work for me,the reason i want to append the  value from column2 instead of a row number is because the column2 is somewhat related to column1 and would make more sense to the user than appending a row number.